# Backup in not getting restore

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I have taken a backup from a database(Sql server 2008 R2).But in machine i have

Sql server 2008.When i am trying it to restore that backup in machine then it is

showing Error.Following is the error message==

The database was backed up was running on a server running version 10.50.1600.

That version is incompatible with the server which is running on version

10.00.1600. So,how can now i restore my file

Comment: Back it up with backward compatibility or create a script from your db in 2008R then run it on 2008 and import data. Here are some details of previous versions. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/29/sql-server-2005-change-database-compatible-level-backward-compatibility/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not restore a later version backup to a previous version. SQLServer 2008 R2 is the later version. Your Alternative is to script out all data and database objects and run those scripts on SQL 2008.
[How to Script out your database](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/07/sql-server-2008-2008-r2-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-data-schema-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/)